# Do these matrices exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vector-spaces

Say you have some non-zero vector in $x$. Can you have two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that:

$$Ax = Bx$$

if $A$ and $B$ aren't the identity matrix?

This isn't homework, just curiosity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure: that just says that $(A-B)x=0$, meaning that $x$ is in the null space of $A-B$. Take $C$ to be any non-zero $n\times n$ matrix with $x$ in its null space and $B$ to be any $n\times n$ matrix, and setting $A=B+C$ gives you such a pair.

Comment: What is $B$ is a diagonal matrix? Would this still be possible?

Comment: @dfg: There’s no restriction on $B$; you just have to make sure that $Cx=0$.

Comment: Adding to Brian's answer: It is also worth noting that if $Ax= Bx$  **for all**  $x$, then it is indeed true that $A=B$.

Comment: It's a great example that in matrix algebra you can not "knock off" an x from left hand side and right hand side, as one would often do in regular algebra.

Answer (score 0):

A good example is Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors. Take $B$ to be a $1\times1$ matrix and call it "$\lambda$" and you have the equation $A\vec{x} = \lambda\vec{x}$. This means that $A$ acts as a scalar transformation on the vector $\vec{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is an $n$-vector then $Ax=Bx$ represents $n$ homogeneous linear constraints for $2n^2$ variables. A common sense (or basic facts about solving homogeneous systems) indicates that there might be many different $A$'s and $B$'s for which this is true.